# Database/Datawarehouse design suggestions

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis, pivot, transformation

We have a legacy ERP system that stores data in flat files. we have replicated these flat files in SQL Server database pretty much as it is.
Some of the sales tables store historical data in multiple columns without storing any dates with them. the name of the column will tell us which month the sales data belong to. Sales01 is current month, Sales02 is previous month, Sales03 is the month before and so on. Same with sales Qty and margin. i.e. Qty01, qty02 and margin01 and margin 02 and so on. This is repeated for each customer and each item sold.

Now, I am working on a small project where I have to design a small DB for reporting with some tables that will be fed by this main database. 
I want to load this data in such a way that these values from each month are stored in rows with a month-year or date from first day of the month in another column so I can use where clause with dates.

Not sure what would the be best way to go? I have written a stored proc in the past to load this data this way, but wonder if there a better way to go. 
Some how I can use SSIS Pivot transformation?
or just use Pivot or similar statement to do this in an SP?

I will most likely be using this practice to built a data warehouse in future.

Comment: In my opinion, don't use SSIS at all if possible. Stored procs are completely acceptable, particulary with a known set of fixed columns like this. If you want a pretty quick result, Power BI can do all of this stuff for you, although it will not give you a reporting database. There are various solutions to what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I will be using this data across multiple reports/dashboards for different set of users. I am working on Power BI for dashboard for this project, and will look into implementing this directly in Power BI.Thanks again